# How to set a file to this drwxrwsrwx permission on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04

How do I set my file permissions to this drwxrwsrwx? I need it to be the same as my folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Edit: Correct Answer is by user112358132134***

---

My wrong answer:

The first character of `drwxrwsrwx` is `d` and that means directory.  You won't be able to set a file so that it's a directory, because it's a file :)

To set all files in the current directory to `-rwxrwsrwx` you can use `chmod 777 *`

To do this recursively, from the current directory use: `chmod -R 777 *`

Try `man chmod` for more info.  Hope this helps.

---

***Edit: Correct Answer is by user112358132134***

---

Edit: Me checking:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm not that good with permissions :) appreciate the help! :)

Comment: You seem to have missed the 's' in 'rws' it is not the same as 'rwx'. user112358132134 seems to have gotten it right.

Comment: indeed i have. I shall edit my answer to reflect. I trust someone can change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 55):

`chmod 777` **does not** apply `rwxrwsrwx`.  This implicitly means `chmod 0777`, would apply `rwxrwxrwx`, and is significantly different from `rwxrwsrwx`.

The permission `rwxrwsrwx` can be applied with:

```
chmod 2777 your_target
```

You can show the effective permission string of a file or directory with:

```
ls -lad your_target
```

A file would look like:

```
-rwxrwsrwx    1 user  group         0 Feb  3 13:24 foo
```

And a directory would look like:

```
drwxrwsrwx    2 user  group      4096 Feb  3 13:24 bar
```

The first character of the string indicates the type of object that it is.  A normal file will have `-` and a directory will have `d`.  There are other possibilities for other objects.

The remaining 9 characters, in order, refer to the read/write/execute permission for the user owner, the read/write/execute permission for the group owner, and then the read/write/execute permission for everyone else.

In your example, the user owner and everyone permissions are `rwx`, which means that the user owner and everyone have permission to read, write, and execute the object.

The group owner permissions in your example are `rws`, which means that the group owner has read, write, and execute process AND the object has the `setguid` bit set (this is the `s` in `rws`).  On a file, the `setgid` bit means that, if the file were executed, that it would be run with the effective rights of the group owner (instead of that of the user who executed it).  On a directory, the `setgid` bit means that, if a file is created in the directory, its group-owner would be that of the directory (instead of that of the user who created it).

You can read about Linux permissions, including what read/write/execute means on files and directories, [here](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/linux-permissions.shtml) and [here](http://evolt.org/node/263).

Comment: Thanks for explaining what s means, couldn't find that anywhere